# Bounds on sum of entries of an idempotent symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, inequality

Suppose that $M$ is symmetric and idempotent, dimensions $n\times n$, and trace $n-k$. Let $e$ ($n\times 1$) be a column of $1$'s.

Let
$$
S_1\equiv e'Me,\quad S_2=\text{Tr}(M'M)=\text{Tr}(MM)=\text{Tr}(M)=n-k;
$$
i.e. $S_1$ is the sum of all entries of $M$ and $S_2$ is the sum of squares of all entries of $M$.

> **Question**: What are some bounds of $S_1$? I only already know $0\leq S_1\leq n\sqrt{(n-k)/n}$ but I'm hoping to find a nonzero lower bound.

Notes on $S_1\leq n\sqrt{(n-k)/n}$: by the Jensen's inequality
$$
\left(\frac{S_1}{n}\right)^2\leq\frac{S_2}{n}=\frac{n-k}{n}\implies\frac{S_1}{n}\leq\sqrt{\frac{n-k}{n}}\implies S_1\leq n\sqrt{\frac{n-k}{n}}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

There is no non-zero lower bound for the case of $k \geq 1$.  In particular, let $U$ be any orthogonal matrix whose first column is $e$.  We can then take
$$
M = U\pmatrix{I\\&0}U^T
$$
for example, in the $2 \times 2$ case, we can take
$$
M = \frac 1{\sqrt 2}\pmatrix{1&-1\\-1&1}
$$